# change paramstyle on python MySQLdb module

Tags: python, mysql

my default mysql paramstle is :'format'

```
>>>MySQLdb.paramstyle
'format'
```

i want to change default paramstyle to 'pyformat' ,because of i can have query something like "WHERE name=%(name)s".
is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible without monkeying around inside the librarie's internals... --  The `paramstyle` is [hardcoded](http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/MySQLdb/MySQLdb/__init__.py#l27) to conform to PEP 249.

Also notice that the [escaping always uses a `tuple`](http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/MySQLdb/MySQLdb/cursors.py#l187) ...

I imagine you *could* get that to work if you replaced:

```
if args is not None:
    query = query % tuple(( get_codec(a, self.encoders)(db, a) for a in args ))
```

with something like:

```
if args is not None:
    if isinstance(args, tuple):
        args = tuple(get_codec(a, self.encoders)(db, a) for a in args)
    elif isinstance(args, dict):
        args = {k: get_codec(a, self.encoders)(db, a) for a in args}
    query = query % args
```

Here you'd probably want to do this in a Cursor subclass -- and you can pass that as an argument to the connection...

Ultimately, this is a bit "hairy" since re-writing the entire execute method will likely force you to use a bunch of stuff that isn't in the "public" API, but it should be possible at least.

Comment: @Mahyar -- Sure there's a way.  The question is how _easy_ is it to do and how much you're willing to rely on implementation details to do it :-)

Comment: @Mahyar -- Interestingly enough, if you read the _docstring_, it acts like the `%(...)` format should be supported, but looking at the code, I have a hard time believing that it is.  :-)